# Where I can find the Bloons TD 5 Deluxe save file?

Tags: bloons-td-5

Where can I find the save file, and how can I edit it?

I tried Google, but only cheat engine results turned up. :(

Comment: That's a flash game, isn't it? It'll depend on what site you're playing on. You might be able to find it in `%APPDATA%\Macromedia\Flash Player\#SharedObjects\<random numbers and letters>`. From there, go to the site you played it on (e.g. kongregate.com) and look for it. As for editing, you can use a `.SOL` editor like **.minerva**.

Comment: Well, this is the deluxe version and is played offline, so is there something else I need to do?

Answer (score 2):

You can find the save file for Bloons TD 5 Deluxe (now known as Bloons TD 5 Steam) at the following location:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\userdata\(your steam ID)\306020\local\data\docs.

OldProfile.save and Profile.save is your save file.